# Error retrieving data from SharePoint list between two dates using javascript caml query

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I am trying to retrieve data between two dates from SharePoint list using CAML javascript. I am getting the data if the two dates are in same month but if the two dates are in different months it is not retrieving any data.
For eg. if the dates are `1-jan-2017` to `20-ja-2017` it is working of if the is `20-jan-2017` to `10-Feb-2017` it is not retrieving any `data.which`. I'm making any error in CAML query it seems.

```
camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where>"+   
    "<And><And>"+                               
        "<Geq>"+
            "<FieldRef Name='Start_Date'/><Value IncludeTimeValue='false' Type='DateTime'>"+RDTA1+"</Value>"+
        "</Geq>"+
        "<Leq>"+
            "<FieldRef Name='Start_Date'/><Value IncludeTimeValue='false' Type='DateTime'>"+RDTA2+"</Value>"+
        "</Leq>"+
    "</And>"+
    "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Employee_Name' LookupId='true'/><Value Type='User'>"+current+"</Value></Eq>"+
    "</And></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Start_Date' Ascending='True'/></OrderBy></Query></View>");
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
```

Comment: this question belongs to https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com, maybe try there

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the date in the format `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ` or use `SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime`